# How to calculate percentage for each cell in a dataframe using ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

My guess is that this is easy using ddply but Im still a newbie at R and can't get my head around it.

I have a  data.frame looking like this

```
txt <- "label var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
lab1 401 80 57 125 118 182 83
lab2 72 192 80 224 182 187 178
lab3 7 152 134 104 105 80 130
lab4 3 58 210 30 78 33 87
lab5 1 2 3 1 1 2 6"

mydata <- read.table(textConnection(txt), sep = " ", header = TRUE)
```

doing this I can transform one variable at a time into percentage

```
mydata$var1 <- round(prop.table(mydata$var1),3)*100
```

But how to do it with all variables (var1:var7) in a data.frame in one stroke?

NOTE: It is going into a function, in which length and number of variables differs from time to time, and hence the code should be sensitive to this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for fancy packages. This will work as long as you want to do it to all but the first column. You could adapt the conditions for what columns are included if `2:ncol` isn't appropriate.

```
t(round(t(mydata[, 2:ncol(mydata)]) / colSums(mydata[, 2:ncol(mydata)]) * 100, 3))
```

And, since you asked about `plyr` and `dplyr` is the improved version of `ddply`, here's how you'd do it with that:

```
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)

mydata %>% melt(id.vars = "label") %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    mutate(prop = round(value / sum(value) * 100, 3)) %>%
    dplyr::select(-value) %>%
    dcast(label ~ variable, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "prop")
```

Convert your data to long format, calculate the proportions, and switch it back to wide. A lot of typing for what Simon O'Hanlon shows to be a quick one-liner, but the `dplyr` method generalizes nicely to whatever sorts of calculations you might want to do.

Comment: @Einnor if this answered your question you should *consider* (read - not obliged) accepting it to show this question has been answered. I notice you haven't accepted any answers to your 6 questions yet. You may want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to see how SO works to help you get the most out of the site.

Comment: @Simon0101 I was not aware that I should accept answers. But will do :)

Comment: @Einnor no problem, I figured you did not know, hence pointing you to the about guide.

Comment: This only works because the all the columns sum up to the same value. Matrix arithmetic is applied by row and not by column. If the next column summed up to a different value the second row in column 2 would not be correct.  @SimonO'Hanlon solution is accurate.

Comment: @Kevin Good catch! I added a couple transposes to fix it, but it definitely makes Simon's answer look even better relative to this one.

Comment: @shujaa, it looks like it works now. I was trying to apply this to a problem I had myself and found it was not working right. Forgot that transposing it would correct that.

Answer (score 5):

Just coerce to a `matrix` and use the margin argument to `prop.table` like so:

```
round( prop.table(as.matrix(df),2) * 100 , 3 )
```

For example

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame( matrix( sample(4 , 12 , repl=TRUE ) , 3 ) )
df
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  2  4  3  2
#2  4  4  4  4
#3  2  1  3  2
round( prop.table(as.matrix(df),2) * 100 , 3 )
#    X1     X2 X3 X4
#[1,] 25 44.444 30 25
#[2,] 50 44.444 40 50
#[3,] 25 11.111 30 25
```

In your example it looks like what I thought were rownames is actually a column of character values. To use `prop.table` on all columns except this first one you can do `prop.table( df[,-1] , margin = 2 )`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this can help you:

```
cbind(label=mydat[,1],as.data.frame(apply(mydat[,-1], 2, function(col) round(prop.table(col),3)*100 )))
```

Comment: You could simplify this slightly like: `data.frame(mydata[1],lapply(mydata[-1],function(x) round(prop.table(x)*100,3) ))`

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem

```
df1 <- head(mtcars[,c(1:2)],2)
sum(df1)

df <- round(as.data.frame(lapply(df1,function(x)x/sum(df1))),2); df;  class(df)

df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) paste0(x,'%'))); df

mpg   cyl
1 0.39% 0.11%
2 0.39% 0.11%
```